# Undo and redo is not working on TextInput in AIR application?

Tags: apache-flex, air, tlf

I've just noticed in my AIR application that redo is not working. It also seems that there it only is going back one step (but sometimes two or three).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:TextArea horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" />
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

I'm using CMD + Z for undo and CMD + Z + Shift for redo. I'm sure this was working at one point. Maybe it was only in the browser?

I'm using Flex 4.6 and AIR 3.6. I'm using Mac 10.10.5. I'm using Firefox 40.3. I also tried it in Safari.

Undo and redo work correctly in the text fields in both of those browsers using the same shortcut combinations listed.

Answer (score 0):

according to docs it should work:

> The Spark TextArea also supports unlimited undo/redo within one
>   editing session. An editing session starts when the control gets
>   keyboard focus and ends when the control loses focus.

but i noticed during development of my app that 
when we use backspace it counts it as separate states
in other cases it see all changes as one

Comment: Yep it should but it does not.